# How to run a loop with a specific interval in casperjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, casperjs

I want to automate clicking a button with `id='vote'` 3 times with an interval of say 5 seconds with **casperjs**, for that I have written the code below

```
 var casper = require('casper').create();

    casper.start('http://www.mysite.com/mypage');

    casper.repeat(3, function() {
        this.click('#vote');
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        console.log('clicked vote ,and voted successfully , and curernt url is  ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
    });
    casper.run();
```

But this only working once, what I want to do is to repeat the loop 3 times with a specific interval, since this is a JavaScript ajax post on clicking the vote button and it updates the database, is it doing all 3 clicks at once? What do I have to do to avoid that, and update the database 3 times?

Comment: Can you try soemthing like this : "casper.start('http://www.mysite.com/mypage').repeat(3, function() {} ;" ?

Comment: No now also ,its clicking only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using [wait](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#wait) and [each](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#each).  The following clicks a button, waits 3 seconds, and loops through each value of array.  The loop works, I can not test your click.

```
var casper = require('casper').create ({
    waitTimeout: 15000,
    stepTimeout: 10000,
    verbose: true,
    viewportSize: {
      width: 1400,
      height: 768
    },
    pageSettings: {
      "userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1262.0 Safari/537.10',
      "loadImages": false,
      "webSecurityEnabled": false,
      "ignoreSslErrors": true
    },
    onWaitTimeout: function() {
        //throw new Error
    },
    onStepTimeout: function() {
        //throw new Error
    }
});

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
  console.log('***REMOTE MESSAGE***:', msg);
  //throw new Error
});

// array of how many clicks
var clicks = [];
clicks[0] = 'click1';
clicks[1] = 'click2';
clicks[2] = 'click3';

casper.start('http://www.google.com/'); //+++ change the url

// function to click button
casper.Clicker = function () {
  this.click('#vote');
  this.echo('I just clicked');
    return true;
};

//function to wait set time
casper.Waiter = function () {
  // adjust wait time between clicks
  this.wait(3000, function() {
    this.echo('I waited for 3 seconds.');
  });
    return true;
};

// loop
casper.then(function() {
  this.each(clicks, function() {
    this.waitFor(function check() {
        return this.Clicker();
    });
    this.waitFor(function check() {
        return this.Waiter();
    }, function then() {
      this.echo('Olayy!');
    });
  });
});

casper.run();
```

If you would like to have a loop with set clicks (not using array) and set intervals:

```
var casper = require('casper').create ({
    waitTimeout: 15000,
    stepTimeout: 10000,
    verbose: true,
    viewportSize: {
      width: 1400,
      height: 768
    },
    pageSettings: {
      "userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1262.0 Safari/537.10',
      "loadImages": false,
      "webSecurityEnabled": false,
      "ignoreSslErrors": true
    },
    onWaitTimeout: function() {
        //throw new Error
    },
    onStepTimeout: function() {
        //throw new Error
    }
});

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
  console.log('***REMOTE MESSAGE***:', msg);
  //throw new Error
});

// how many clicks
var clickCount = 3

casper.start('http://www.google.com'); //+++ change the url

// function to click button
casper.Clicker = function () {
  this.click('#vote');
  this.echo('I just clicked');
    return true;
};

//function to wait set time
casper.Waiter = function () {
  // adjust wait time between clicks
  this.wait(3000, function() {
    this.echo('I waited for 3 seconds.');
  });
    return true;
};

// loop
casper.then(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < clickCount; i++) {
    this.waitFor(function check() {
        return this.Clicker();
    });
    this.waitFor(function check() {
        return this.Waiter();
    });
  }
  this.echo('Olayy!');
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Can i pass a number instead of an array(clicks) ??

Comment: Each iterates over provided array items.  So to use a click variable, see my code above - I changed the each to a for loop.